# Import repetitiv HTML fragments in to other html files using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a Node.js project with multiple html pages. I want to lower the repetitiveness of code fragments in each file, e.g. the head tag/fragment will stay the same in every file, with a title and some css stylesheets etc.

I want my **index.html** file to looks something like this...

```
import head.html

<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello world!</p>
  </div>
</body>

import footer.html
```

... **head.html** file to look something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

... **footer.html** to look something like this...

```
<footer>
  *some div with copyright stuff*
</footer>
```

How will I achieve this using node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a templating engine](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/). I'm a fan of [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), but there are many alternatives.

It's [include syntax](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include) is very similar to your hypothetical version.

```
{% include "html.html" %}

<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello world!</p>
  </div>
</body>

{% include "footer.html" %}
```

(Note, however, that the `<footer>` should be *inside* the `<body>`).

Then you just write a little code to combine them:

```
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const index = nunjucks.render('index.html');
// Then write index to a file or whatever
```

You might want to use [an existing static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/) or use nunjucks as a [template engine for Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).